# JavaScript classes and eventhandlers with "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

So im running into a bit of confusion on "this" in event handlers and properly preserving them. I have done a good bit of googling and have figured out "Why" this is changing when calling an element......but not really a way to fix it for my situation.

I've set up a sample concept here: https://jsfiddle.net/msmith1114/xu4zbppz/8/

You've got two buttons and a simple class. The main part im concerned about is setting up the jquery event handlers for these buttons in my class prototype (I've posted a separate question about where event handlers should "usually" go when referring to javascript classes here: [ES6 Classes/Object oriented and Event Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691282/es6-classes-object-oriented-and-event-handlers))

and one of the answers does go into a little detail on "this" and it makes sense.

Just looking at the class:

```
class Player {
  constructor() {
    $(".demo").click(function() {
      console.log(this)
      console.log($(this).text())
    });
    this.color
    this.name = 'Player 1'
  }

  printName(player) {
    if (player == 1)
      console.log(this.name + "'s color is " + this.color)
  }
}
```

ER, how can I set an event handler for constructor items on clicks. IE what if I want to store the `this.color` (for the player class) equal to the `button.text()` value? If I bind `$(this)` then I can't refer to the button text....however if I don't bind it, I can't really store it since I can't really say in the event handler `this.color = $(this).text()` as great as it would be if that worked.

Or is this just straight up bad practice? Im just starting this classes and really diving into Object Oriented javascript...and I learned a lot about `this` and object creation, but when it came to implementing it into DOM related JS code I didn't really know where to put my event handlers. (Such as in a tic-tac-toe game, i've created a "board" class so it seems to me the event handlers would be in the "board" class itself....am I going about this the wrong way?

Or is there a workaround that makes sense. I've seen some examples that assign the click event handler to variables....but im not sure I understand the point of that (they were mostly non-jquery code anyways).

Comment: What is `this.color` in the constructor supposed to do?

Comment: Nothing this is literally just a sample I threw together it wasn't super well thought out ha

Comment: Although I do not think this exactly the same as the duplicate because I understand how to switch between `this` as the object and `this` as the button that's clicked. But now how to correctly be able to use both items.

Comment: The answer at the other question says: **2. Store reference to context/this inside another variable**. So you use another variable for the object, while `this` in the callback is the button that's clicked.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough, the question was a few years old so I didn't know if there was maybe "new" ways ha.

Comment: The question is old, but the first answer is only 8 months old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use `this` in your jQuery event handler to get the element that triggered the event, you can also get it using `event.target`.

I would recommend you use that together with an arrow function to get the desired effect:

```
class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Player 1'
        $(".demo").click(ev => {
            console.log(ev.target)
            console.log($(ev.target).text())
            console.log(this.name)
        });
    }
}
```

If you do not want to use arrow functions for some reason, a commonly used workaround is to assign `this` to a variable, e.g. `_this`, for reference in callbacks that have a different `this` scope:

```
class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Player 1'
        const _this = this;
        $(".demo").click(function (ev) {
            console.log(ev.target)
            console.log($(ev.target).text())
            console.log(_this.name)
        });
    }
}
```

…or you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Player 1'
        $(".demo").click(function (ev) {
            console.log(ev.target)
            console.log($(ev.target).text())
            console.log(this.name)
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions? Thanks for that - something I'd not come across before.

Comment: The OP also mentioned using them in the question

Comment: But keep in mind that they may not work in older browsers without a transpiler like Babel. The same goes for ES6 classes, of course

Comment: Can I use suggests everything but opera mobile and IE.

Comment: This is good, can you perhaps show the example without arrow functions (so i'll know what it "would" look like. Im assuming it would bind(this) to the click handler?

Comment: sure, added it to the answer

Comment: @PatrickHund great, thanks. Would adding .bind also work? ( i know the _this = this is pretty common.

Comment: yup, added that as well

Comment: @PatrickHund Thanks! is there really any benefit to either? I guess using arrows probably makes the most sense for ES6

Comment: I think so, too, I use arrows almost every time I create an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the bug .. try it!

```
constructor(){
    $(".demo").click(function() {
        console.log(this)
            console.log($(this).text())
    });
    this.color
    this.name = 'Player 1'
}
```

The problem was caused by the BIND function.

Comment: You have `.bind` in the wrong place. But if you do it like this, `$(this)` won't work, because it will be bound to the object, not the DOM element.

Comment: You are right!!